# How can I set up a conditions-based auto-scrolling scheme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have these two auto-scrolling components:

ScrollToTop

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: 'instant', // Optional
    });
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

ScrollToAnchor

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function ScrollToAnchor() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const lastHash = useRef('');

  // listen to location change using useEffect with location as dependency
  // https://jasonwatmore.com/react-router-v6-listen-to-location-route-change-without-history-listen
  useEffect(() => {
    if (location.hash) {
      lastHash.current = location.hash.slice(1); // safe hash for further use after navigation
    }

    if (
      lastHash.current &&
      document.getElementById(lastHash.current)
    ) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        document
          .getElementById(lastHash.current)
          ?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
        lastHash.current = '';
      }, 100);
    }
  }, [location]);

  return null;
}

export default ScrollToAnchor;
```

they are being used inside my index.js as follows:

```
createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ScrollToTop />
            <ScrollToAnchor />
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
);
```

the results have been rather unpredictable... Is there a way to set up proper conditional auto-scrolling scheme, instead of relying on order between components?